# Subordinator - conditions for the Levy triple

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, levy-processes

different books write Levy Khinchnin's formula in different ways and thus I have a problem with understanding the conditions that Levy's triple must satisfy for the process to be a subordinator. In my notation, Levy process with characteristic triple $(b,\sigma, \nu)$ has characteristic function:
$$\phi_{X_t}(u)=\exp\{t(ibu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2u^2+\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{iux}-1-iux1_{|x|<1})\nu(dx))\}$$

What conditions, then, must be satisfy by the levy triple for the process to be subordinator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your convention, the characteristic triple of a subordinator satisfies:

- $\sigma = 0$ (no Brownian part),
- $\nu$ has support in $(0,\infty)$ (positive jumps) and $\int_0^\infty (1\wedge x) \, \nu(dx) < \infty$ (bounded variation),
- $b - \int_0^1 x\,\nu(dx) \geqslant 0$ (positive drift).

This is Theorem 1.3.15 in Applebaum's *Lévy Processes and Stochastic Calculus*, see also Chapter 3 of Bertoin's *Lévy Processes*.

Notice that when working with subordinators, it is more convenient to use the Laplace exponent instead of the characteristic exponent. It is defined by $\mathbb{E}[\exp(-\lambda X_t)] = \exp(-t\psi(\lambda))$ and for subordinators the Lévy-Khintchine formula reads
$$\psi(\lambda) = d \lambda + \int_0^\infty (1-e^{-\lambda x}) \, \nu(dx)$$
where $d\geqslant 0$ and $\nu$ a measure on $(0,\infty)$ satisfying $\int_0^\infty (1\wedge x) \, \nu(d x) <\infty$.

Comment: So  assumption that $b\ge 0$ is not enough? Because many book states that $b$ is drift so why we subtract $\int_0^1 x\,\nu(dx)$?

Comment: The assumption $\int (1\wedge x)\, \nu(dx) < \infty$ implies that $e^{iux}-1$ is $\nu(dx)$-integrable. Thus, we have
$$\phi_{X_t}(u) = \exp\left\{t\left(iu\underbrace{\left(b-\int_0^1 x\, \nu(d x)\right)}_{=:d}+ \int_0^\infty (e^{iux}-1)\, \nu(dx)\right)\right\} $$ where $d$ is the real drift. Going back to the Lévy-Ito decomposition, one would have $X_t = dt +  
\sum_{s\leqslant t} \Delta X_s$. Notice that the sum $\sum_{s\leqslant t} \Delta X_s$ is finite a.s. as $\int (1\wedge x)\, \nu(dx) < \infty$. Here, it should be easier to understand the need for $d$ (and not $b$!) to be positive.